# Target single breakpoint only

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I have a container with multiple divs. On mobile only I want all cards to have red text. On `sm` breakpoint only I want all `even` cards to have blue text.

My current code is this:

The problem is, while in `sm` breakpoint, it still sees the previous red. This is good for most of the time, but in this specific case I need to make it as if it wasn't there. I can fight it with `sm:text-black` but this will get hairy as if I want to custom `md` breakpoint only too, then I have to fight the `sm`, and etc to `lg` and `xl`.

The current code I have produces this at mobile:

[image]

And produces this at `sm` breakpoint:

[image]

The problem is, when enter `sm` breakpoint, it leaves everything that was previously red, as red. I want those to return to default.

I was hoping on `sm`, all the non-even will be default color like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can define explicitly like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<section class="text-gray-600 body-font">
  <div class="container px-5 py-24 mx-auto">
    <div class="flex flex-wrap -m-4 ">
      <div class="p-4 lg:w-2/4">
        <div class="h-full bg-gray-100 bg-opacity-75 px-8 pt-16 pb-24 rounded-lg overflow-hidden text-center relative">
          <h2 class="tracking-widest text-xs title-font font-medium text-gray-400 mb-1">CATEGORY</h2>
          <h1 class="title-font sm:text-2xl text-xl font-medium mb-3 text-red-400 sm:even:text-black">Raclette Blueberry Nextious Level</h1>
          <p class="leading-relaxed mb-3">Photo booth fam kinfolk cold-pressed sriracha leggings jianbing microdosing tousled waistcoat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="p-4 lg:w-2/4">
        <div class="h-full bg-gray-100 bg-opacity-75 px-8 pt-16 pb-24 rounded-lg overflow-hidden text-center relative">
          <h2 class="tracking-widest text-xs title-font font-medium text-gray-400 mb-1">CATEGORY</h2>
          <h1 class="title-font sm:text-2xl text-xl font-medium mb-3 text-red-400 sm:even:text-blue-500">Ennui Snackwave Thundercats</h1>
          <p class="leading-relaxed mb-3">Photo booth fam kinfolk cold-pressed sriracha leggings jianbing microdosing tousled waistcoat.</p>
         
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="p-4 lg:w-2/4">
        <div class="h-full bg-gray-100 bg-opacity-75 px-8 pt-16 pb-24 rounded-lg overflow-hidden text-center relative">
          <h2 class="tracking-widest text-xs title-font font-medium text-gray-400 mb-1">CATEGORY</h2>
          <h1 class="title-font sm:text-2xl text-xl font-medium text-red-400 mb-3 sm:even:text-black">Selvage Poke Waistcoat Godard</h1>
          <p class="leading-relaxed mb-3">Photo booth fam kinfolk cold-pressed sriracha leggings jianbing microdosing tousled waistcoat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="p-4 lg:w-2/4">
        <div class="h-full bg-gray-100 bg-opacity-75 px-8 pt-16 pb-24 rounded-lg overflow-hidden text-center relative">
          <h2 class="tracking-widest text-xs title-font font-medium text-gray-400 mb-1">CATEGORY</h2>
          <h1 class="title-font sm:text-2xl text-xl font-medium mb-3 text-red-400 sm:even:text-blue-500">Master Knuckle Raindogs</h1>
          <p class="leading-relaxed mb-3">Photo booth fam kinfolk cold-pressed sriracha leggings jianbing microdosing tousled waistcoat.</p>
         
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```